# How best to access alarm data after mysql insert

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

My system inserts an alarm data row with multiple columns into a mysql database table each time a new alarm occurs. Need to be able to email the most recent alarm data row each time it occurs.

Have tried using a trigger that calls a php script procedure for querying, fetching, and emailing the last inserted row, and while all actions are occuring properly, I'm not getting the current inserted alarm data, but instead I'm getting the alarm data row just previous to the just inserted alarm data. Have tried using both LIMIT 0,1 and LIMIT 1 at the end of the SELECT statement, but still not getting most recent insert data.

I'm assuming that the trigger procedure CALL is occuring before the alarm data has actually been inserted into the DB. (using AFTER INSERT on trigger) Was thinking maybe a crontab to initiate a shell script to check for new alarms every minute, but unsure how to write the script to only initiate the email once each time a new alarm is inserted into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

While working on History Tables I get the Last Insert Values Like this in my Trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db`.`table_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `table` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO `db`.`table_history`
(`id`,
`contactinfo`,
`ag_contact_type_fk`,
`ag_uq_pid_fk`,
`hist_entry_type`)
VALUES
(NEW.id,
NEW.contactinfo,
NEW.ag_contact_type_fk,
NEW.ag_uq_pid_fk,
"insert");
```

This way I get the Values of the last Inserted row each time with "NEW.xyz".

Maybe this could help you along with getting the data in your trigger.

Comment: Franco, Thanks for responding to my initial question. I've seen similar code in my research of this problem, but had a few questions. Why do you use CREATE DEFINER instead of CREATE TRIGGER? What does the "insert" at the end mean? What would be the best way to email the NEW values? Could I initiate a procedure CALL at the end of code style shown above?